# Viewing individual form response shows different id to one given by script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to determine how the URLs are structured and I can't work it out. In [the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE18g.png) I know that the first ID is that of the form itself but I cannot work out what the second ID is. 
The code I run gets the most recent response and its ID

```
FormApp.openByUrl(source_sheet.getFormUrl()).getResponses().pop().getId();
\\ this is the result: 2_ABaOnud9bHGGKKjxqZ5KjayeAOjmxt45PHNLah9EbY_sUUDBP8Hz3MGEqH2z6j4
```

but the url shows a different id for the in this section

edit#response=ACYDBNhCIRYZMUyyHRbrOvOeWKMSiBHmjPplwQUCk7KhTwuPbCU7olfuaiSEn4E

I would like to be able to get this segment of the url through the script because I want to automate getting this url and printing to pdf

Comment: Use the location.hash function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location